# probable or probably?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

In the following sentence, which one is right in the viewpoint of grammatical structure? Why?

Notice: In the main source, it is "probable".

> It seems **probable** that there is no single explanation but that there
>   are elements of the truth in several of the hypotheses.
>
> It seems **probably** that there is no single explanation but that there
>   are elements of the truth in several of the hypotheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem is a linking verb and it takes adjective after it.

> e.g It seems probable to ask students to buy a dictionary.
>   You seem happy.

Probable is an adjective and probably is an adverb

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say.

If you want to say: "**it is possible** that there is no single explanation..."

then you need to use:

> It seems *(that it is)* **probable** that there is...

If you want to say that "seems" is not certain, you need to use "probably", but with *different word order*:

> It **probably** seems that ...